# Create a usermanager from a Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a UserService that looks like this:

```
public class UserService : IUserStore<UserModel>, IUserLoginStore<UserModel>, IUserPasswordStore<UserModel>, IUserSecurityStampStore<UserModel>, IUserService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }
    //create the user
}
```

I want to create a usermanager from this service. I have created a class that I call IdentityStartup, and I looks like this:

```
public class IdentityStartup
{
    public static Func<UserManager<UserModel>> UserManagerFactory { get; private set; }
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    //public static Func<RoleManager<Role>> RoleManagerFactory { get; private set; }

    public IdentityStartup(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }


    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/home/index")
        });

        // configure the user manager
        UserManagerFactory = () =>
        {
            var usermanager = new UserManager<UserModel>(_userService);

            // allow alphanumeric characters in username
            usermanager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<UserModel>(new UserService())
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false
            };
            return usermanager;
        };

    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to pass _userService as a parameter, but that don't work, because it don't work to convert from IUserService to Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore

I want to use my UserService as the UserStore.

Comment: I think your `UserService` needs to also accept a generic for `UserModel` to be passed.

Comment: @Tim: Can you give me a example?

Comment: `public class UserService<UserModel> : IUserStore<UserModel>...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make interface `IUserService` implement an interface `IUserStore<UserModel>`

Something like this:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }
    //create the user
}

public interface IUserService : IUserStore<UserModel>, IUserLoginStore<UserModel>, IUserPasswordStore<UserModel>, IUserSecurityStampStore<UserModel>
{
   ...
}
```

You could also make IUserService generic if you want.

Comment: @score4er: Thank you buddy :)

Answer (score -1):

add a method to `IUserService` that returns an `IUserStore<UserModel>`

```
IUserStore<UserModel> asUserStore()
```

In your implementation, since the `IdentityService` implements `IUserStore<UserModel>` it can return itself

```
public IUserStore<UserModel> asUserStore() = {
  return this;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you control `IUserService`, if not you need to cast `_userService` to `IUserStore[UserModel]` to pass it into the function, which is ugly because it couples the implementation to the interface..  not all `IUserService` instances cam be cast like that

Comment: When I try to add IUserStore[UserModel] to my interface, I only get the following: Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration...

Comment: sorry, im used to scala, i think you want angle brackets for c# - updated

Comment: Jason: Thank you for your answer. But where should I add public IUserStore<UserModel> asUserStore() = this;? In my factory class?

Comment: in the `UserService` class

Comment: But what should that method return? :P

Comment: In op's code, not all IUserService implementations will support IUserStore<UserModel> interface potentially. So this common method you proposed is not so common. A better solution is to implement IUserStore and other interfaces within IUserService interface, not within UserService class.

Comment: @scor4er: Can you give me an example what you are thinking?

Comment: Compare this two guys:  `public class UserService : IUserStore<UserModel>, IUserService`, `public class UserService2 : IUserService`. That's why you don't want to add AsUserStore() method to the IUserService interface. Because IUserService has nothing common with IUserStore currently.

Comment: But if you just move IUserStore<UserModel> implementation from UserService class to IUserService interface it will make your design cleaner. See my answer nearby.